# Is it possible to have the system/kernel reverse x-axis touch input?

Tags: touchscreen, kernel, samsung-galaxy-s-6, input-methods, scripts

I have a galaxy S6 G920F.

I have this problem with my touchscreen. The x-axis input is reversed. When I touch it on the left part it registers the touch on the right etc..

Is there a way to just have the system reverse the input so that it becomes normal again? some edits inside init.d script or some change in the kernel image or something?

I have tried flashing more than one firmware, kernels, roms everything with no luck. Please, is it possible to change how the device interprets touch input in order to reverse input the x-axis?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is the ribbon cable for the touchscreen installed backwards?

Comment: @MatthewRead No, I haven't replaced the touchscreen. I actually didn't go through this in the post because I though it was irrelevant. I had installed a rom, then had some issues and decided to go back to the stock firmware, where I wasn't able to get it to boot after flashing it with odin. I had to install a custom kernel (which I made sure is for my correct model) and got the problem. Now whatever I do the problem won't go away.